# Does the jquery autosuggest plugin allow you to enter your own values (not from the dropdown)?

Tags: jquery, json, autosuggest

i really [like this plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) but it seems to be a flaw in it that its missing the feature to be able to create you own tags on the fly (its restrict to choosing from the dropdown list).

is there any other plugin that supports this additional feature or does the autosuggest plugin have anyway of supporting entering my own tags.  I would rather not have 2 textboxes (1 for checking for existing items and one for entering new ones).

Comment: ooo - i'm not stalking you, honest. :). just want to add, that adding your own tag is easy (as per example below - tab key). however, you have to then figure a way to save that new tag. this unfortunately is where your skill as a developer has to kick in. there isn't a save method for the simple reason that the implementation detail is open and down to you to create. fwiw - in the space of an hour, i had all the basics running in both directions enough to convince me that this was a usable bit of kit. other than pasting my code, i'm not sure what else to suggest in support of this plugin...

Comment: jim - thanks for the feedback. i am not trying to get out of writing code but ultimately for something like tags, i would have thought this was a "101" feature as the vanilla use case is people having to create their own tags.. Tab key seems to work but this plugin doesn't work in IE6 so thats a showstopper for me.  Ultimatley i think i am going to write one that mimics SOF's tags functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It (the demo sample) let me enter a tag that wasn't part of the demo set of tags.

[image]

I've never used this plug-in, so I may be missing something with the underlying implementation.

I do know the jQuery UI AutoComplete widget supports this.  Here's the document [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), and there's a good example on having multiple tags ("multiple values sample") that aren't part of a custom data set.  That was the sample that I learned from to build my page.

The downside with the jQuery UI widget is that a lot of the fancy styling is up to you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what browser are you using.  I am not able to enter my own tag in the same example you are referring to. are you just typing something and hitting ENTER ??

Comment: Interesting.  I used Chrome for the screenshot I attached.  I typed my tag and hit the <TAB> key.  I just tried the site on IE8 and I get a javascript error when the page loads.  Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: In looking at the JS error I'm getting in IE8, looks like the site may just have jQuery referenced incorrectly.  (The jQuery.js library is throwing a 'blah is undefined' error.)  I doubt there's a problem with jQuery.  :)